# What are wire edges?

Tags: edges, selection-tools

In the select > select all by trait > non manifold menu there is the option "Wire". What are these wire edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wires are edges that do not belong to any face.

From [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-all-by-traits)