# What is a non-manifold vertex?

Tags: modeling, vertices, topology, geometry, error

I am experiencing a lot of issues with the topology of a specific object I am modelling. Currently I have an issue with 'non-manifold vertices on it as shown by the screen shot below:

[image: vertices]

The mesh issue I have highlighted is found by operating `Select>Select all by Trait>non-manifold` and checking only the 'vertices' option in options menu as pictured in the bottom left of my screenshot.

I would **specifically** like to be able to identify what **the tool** `Select all by Trait` looks for when the 'vertices' option is selected, so I can better address my topology problem

I have read a fair bit about what can cause non-manifold geometry but simply non-manifold 'vertices' doesn't really mean a whole lot to me, can anyone shed any light

Here is the blend file: [image]

**N.B:** I have recalculated internal and external normals as well as 'merged by distance' multiple times which doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with this problem the detailing of this is actually outlined in the blender docs [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting.html?highlight=select%20trait/selecting.html?highlight=select%20trait#select-all-by-trait)

The docs say:

> Vertices:
>
> Selects vertices that belong to wire and multiple face edges, isolated vertices, and vertices that belong to non-adjoining faces.

In the attempt not to repeat the good descriptions that exist elsewhere on this stack:

- Wire edges: [What are wire edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127253/what-are-wire-edges)
- Multiple face edges:

[image: Multiple_f_example]

- Isolated vertices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)#Types_of_vertices
- Vertices which share non-adjoining faces:

[image: Vertices]

**N.B:** if you hover over each option in the `Select all by Trait` menu you get a tooltip about each option:

[image: tooltip]

**This is all my best answer as to each scenario, if edits are required please go ahead**